# Migrating Outlook to new PC

Tags: microsoft-outlook, migration

Im moving to new PC (from Win 7 / Outlook 2010) to Win 10 / Outlook 2019)

Do I really have to create new .pst files by explicitly exporting?   Thats what just about any help post Ive found here or elsewhere suggests.
Can I not just copy the current pst files to the new machine (and then import them)?

Comment: Everything is probably available on the mail server, so you shouldn't really "migrate", just login to your account in the new outlook and it'll download everything.

Comment: Interesting.  First time Ive seen this suggested!   (But still copy over backup / archive type pst files 'just in case').   Would the download be slow - I guess I can let it cook overnight?   Main pst file is about 8 GB ...

Comment: I always just copy the PST files to the new machine. It's not the PST files that are usually the problem, though, but recreating all the email accounts.

Answer (score 0):

What’s your account type? Exchange, POP or IMAP?

For Exchange account, all items are saved on the server. You can directly configure your Exchange account on Outlook 2019.

For IMAPaccount, not all the items are saved on the server. To avoid losing data, it’s recommended to backup your mailbox to a PST file and then import it to your new client.

For POP account, items are saved in account PST files.You can copy the current pst files to the new machine.

What are these PST files? For archive PST files, you can directly copy them to new PC and import back to Outlook client.

I found a similar thread in TechNet forum for your reference: 
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/01dca0b9-2273-44ac-b663-b24e46c6ee72/moving-outlook-365-file-from-old-pc-to-new-pc?forum=outlook